# Images not found when deploying Sails JS to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, sails.js, production-environment

I have developed a Sails.js application which is working as expected locally. However, when I deploy it to production (Heroku) the images in the "/assets/images/"-folder cannot be found (404).

I know there are some tasks that transfer the files in the "/assets"-folder to a ".tmp/public"-folder to be accessible when the application is being lifted. The .js- and .less-files are being loaded as expected, but not the images.

How can I make sure that the "/assets/images"-folder is being transferred to the public-folder as well?

Comment: You can't. As far I remember Heroku does not provide this kind of services. U need to use a third party service like Amazon s2 or Dropbox.

Comment: Sails uses grunt tasks to compile static assets (js/css/templates) and make them available to the app. You probably need to add a task to copy your images to the .tmp directory

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue. 
The main idea is to make an **uploads** folder in *.tmp*.
And make a symbolic link in **public** folder leading to **uploads**.
The problem is that Grunt rewrite all the content of '.tmp/public' every time we lift application.

Thus I made a proper Grunt task which simply creates symlink.

1. `sudo npm install grunt-contrib-symlink`
2. Create Grunt task in *tasks/config*. And name it smth like *symlink.js*.

   ```
   module.exports = function(grunt) {

     grunt.config.set('symlink', {
         dev: {

                 src: '.tmp/uploads/**',
                 dest: '.tmp/public/uploads/'

         }
     });

      grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-symlink');
   };
   ```
3. And finally add task to *tasks/register/compileAssets.js*.

   ```
   module.exports = function (grunt) {
       grunt.registerTask('compileAssets', [
           'clean:dev',
           'jst:dev',
           'less:dev',
           'copy:dev',
           'coffee:dev',
           'symlink:dev'
       ]);
   };
   ```